# Whose economy does improve?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[From an article in the Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/trump-is-blaming-democrats-for-separating-migrant-families-at-the-border-heres-why-this-isnt-a-surprise/2018/05/27/c07810d8-61d3-11e8-a69c-b944de66d9e7_story.html?hpid=hp_hp-top-table-main_trumpimmigration-810pm%3Ahomepage%2Fstory&noredirect=on):

> The surge in illegal border crossings is expected to continue as the
>   economy improves and warmer weather arrives.

Which "economy" is improving?  The economy of the illegal migrants' country (such as Mexico)? The U.S. economy?  The migrants' personal income?

Comment: It's surprising that this is unclear.   The previous sentence is *"... officials have made clear that children will be separated from parents who enter **the country** illegally."*  "The country is the United States, so in the following sentence "the economy" is the US economy.  I'm sure that even in your own language, if the author meant the immigrants' economies, the change in direction would have been clearly signaled.

Comment: @Andrew, I have never thought the economy of The U.S. would have been bad (only bad can be "improving", right?)

And, I have thought, maybe the economy of Mexico is improving, that someone had wanted to go to America, but They had had not money, now, they have some money (to pay for their trip or to pay for illegal immigration broker).

Comment: Perhaps but again since in the previous sentence the article was talking about the United States, the author would have to make it clear that he's now talking about the *Mexican* economy, *"... as the **Mexican** economy improves and warmer weather arrives"*  Otherwise it would confuse everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you cite is written from a US perspective and talks about immigrants coming **to** the US.
If the immigrant's home country's economy was improving they would have little incentive to leave.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really a question about English. People typically enter countries illegally because they want to work there (it's much harder to get a work permit and work legally). If the economy in their home country was improving, they wouldn't need to go somewhere else to work. So the article means that the U.S. economy is improving, which means more jobs that the migrants could do, and better pay for them.

In a comment, you say

> I have never thought the economy of The U.S. would have been bad (only bad can be "improving", right?)

No. Improve just means "get better" and anything that isn't perfect could get better. Also, you have to remember that people feel changes in their situation much more than they see the global picture. If people in the U.S. find that their cost of living is increasing faster than their wages, they're going to think "The economy is bad because we have less money available than we used to" and not "I'm glad I have a job in a rich country, because that's so much better than being unemployed in a poor country."